# ajax not working in header.php

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am learning Ajax in WordPress and referring some tutorial. Now I have made this Ajax script with simple form having name field. I am calling this script in header.php file. After implementing I am getting `0`. Why and How to fix it. Can someone guide me why this things happening.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "http://localhost/woocommerce/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: newCustomerForm,
            success:function(data){
                $("#feedback").html(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }  
        });

        return false;
}
```

I will appreciate If someone guide me :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your ajax call

```
action  : 'search_action',
url: "http://localhost/woocommerce/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: newCustomerForm,
```

and than u need a function whitch will be called by wordpress if a ajax requests gets in:

```
function ajax_handler() {

    $response = array( 'status' => 'error' );

    // do your thing here
    // $_POST is available
    // and and something like $response['text'] = 'all done'; or so
    $response['status']     = 'success';


    header( 'Content: application/json' );
    echo json_encode( $response );
    die;

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_action', 'ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_action', 'ajax_handler' );
```

as you can see one action is called for logged in users and one for not logged in users (wp_ajax_nopriv_search_action). Those 2 actions call the same function in this case.

Read more here:
http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the `jQuery`'s with `$`

Update:
**You have still not changed all the jQuery's to $!**
Change:

```
jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();
```

to:

```
$('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var newCustomerForm = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: I tried but not working :(. after replacing page is redirect to 404 page

Comment: Read my answer again, please.

Comment: Have you linked the jQuery Javascript file?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Have you linked it? `<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` -- BEFORE your custom jquery

Comment: No i did not include any jQuery.

Comment: That's a problem then. :) You must include jQuery to use jQuery! :P